# How to get selected checkbox id from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have text box(for live search) and whenever i enter more than 3 characters then
result is showing (from database) via ajax response as checkboxes with name, I just want to get id of checkboxes ?
Here is my script,I am trying with "onclick" but unable to get "selected checkbox id",How can i do this ?

```
<script>
$('#merchantname').keyup(function() {
 var merchantname = $(this).val();
 if(merchantname.length>= 3){
         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
               url: "<?php echo base_url('Newsletter/GetMerchantName');?>",
               cache : false,
              data: {'merchantname': merchantname},
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },   
            success: function(response) {
                $('#sparepartList').empty();
                $.each(response, function(key,value) 
                {
                    let li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + value.merchantId + '" name="merchantName[]" value="' + value.merchantName + '" onclick="loadTweets()" />' +
                                '<input type="text" name="sparepart" value="' + value.merchantName + '" /></li>');
                        $('#sparepartList').append(li);
                        });
                $("#loading-image").hide();
            },
            error: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                } 
    })
    return false;
 }
});
</script>     
    <script>
        function loadTweets(){
            var val = this.checked ? this.id : '';
            alert(val);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: [`async: false` is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: try to pass `this.id` in your onclick function i.e `loadTweets(this.id);`

Comment: @M.Hemant: i tried but not working showing "undefined"

Comment: First of all check if the id `id="' + value.merchantId + '"` is correct, for this inspect the checkbox element and see if it have a well defined `id`